# JavaScript. Count the number of symbols in the given string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

How would you solve this challenge using only string methods, array methods, and loops?

> Count the number of 'xx' in the given string. We'll say that
> overlapping is allowed, so 'xxx' contains 2 'xx'.
>
> Examples:

```
countXX('abcxx') → 1
countXX('xxx') → 2
countXX('xxxx') → 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first step is to try writing some code.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment and that is not really what stack overflow is for. Could you give more context on why you need this answered?

Comment: Look up [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Thank you, friend, I'm trying to solve it for longer than an hour. Already tried to convert string to array, loop through then to join the elements with certain indexes, then with if statement increment the count, but it doesn't work. Just don't want to spam with all my wrong solutions

Comment: Friends, it's not homework, just a task from a coding bat.  I'm just learning, so wanted to check and analyze quick and easy solutions from experienced coders.

Comment: As always, you should post the code you've tried that isn't working. Stack Overflow is not here to solve your task from beginning to end for you.

Comment: take it easy, man. I got you,no problem

Comment: Sorry for the aggressive tone, but the way the question was asked made it seem like it was copied and pasted from a homework assignment.

Comment: `countXX('xxxxx') → 4
countXX('xxxxxx') → 5
countXX('xxxxxxx') → 6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = 'abcxxx';
const asArray = Array.from(input);    // get ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x", "x"]

// Make 2 arrays
const array1 = asArray.slice(1);      // get ["b", "c", "x", "x", "x"]
const array2 = asArray.slice(0, -1);  // get ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]

// Combine arrays to get array of pairs
const pairsArray = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length && i < array2.length; i++) {
    pairsArray.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
}

// Now pairsArray is: ["ab", "bc", "cx", "xx", "xx"]

// Count "xx" in pairs array
const answer = pairsArray.filter(pair => pair === "xx").length;

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
countX('abcxx') - 1
```

This would work formal strings, except if they contain a single `x`.